# Where is the Menu trash in Joomla 3.1?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

Can't find the menu trash page anywhere. Googling this only produced Joomla 2.5 or earlier and these proved useless.

I need to empty it as I need to rename another menu with it's predecessor's name.

Comment: You might want to consider Little Helper, it features centralized trash for Joomla. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/24016

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure to choose "Main Menu" after you open the "Menu" menu.

If you select "Menu Manager" you will end up in the wrong place (I had the same conundrum a couple of weeks ago!)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found it by accident. Select Status -> Trashed.

Comment: +1 for you for finding your answer yourself. You posted answer while I was composing. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You can select the status's dropdown menu and select trashed.In trashed, you can then recover them or delete them